# PHP use case scenarion when should I use function __construct

Tags: php, oop

I am starting to learn PHP OOP following a prescribed book, however it is not the best of books IMO and results in quite a bit of confusion especially the section on PHP classes.

Consider the folllowing:

```
     Class User{

    function setName($newName)
        {
            $this->name = $newName;
        }

        function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
}
```

The class has no construct method:

**Thus, my Questions:**

1. If the class above had a property `$name` and a function __construct refrencing the `$name` var would it have been necessary to create the `setName()` method?
2. If yes, When is it appropriate to build a construct method? And when is it not? As a general rule of thumb am I correct to assume it is good practice to build a construct method for all class properties?

Any advice / help / references appreciated.

Comment: Even if you passed in `$name` into the constructor you'd still want these methods to manipulate the name value rather than using a public property that you have no control over.

Comment: Yes, you can create a `__construct($name)` to set the $name (or have the `__construct()` to call `setName()` internally to do that). In general, __construct() would need if you'd want to setup some initial status of a class. Whether you would need the `setName()` method or not depends on whether you would need to mutate the $name in future.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios where setName and __construct can be used.

1 - When you create an object of class and you want to class should be initailized with default parameter then go with __construct method.

```
$obj = new UserName('john');
```

Above method cannot be used multiple times right. so that you need a way where you can change a name without creating an object every time that where setName comes in picture.

2 - setName is way to reinitialize the name property whenever it's required.

```
  $obj = new UserName('john'); //1st step
  echo $obj->getName(); //john displays
  //may be some sql query that gets name from db
  $obj->setName('david'); //here you cannot re-instantiate the object to set the name using construct method.
  $obj->getName(); //david displays
```

Hope this heps!!